# YII2 download form backend movies without compression

Tags: html, download, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

The user is upload files from frontend, and after that the administration must download the video, but when i try to download it the same video is compression ... real size of video is 28MB when i  downloaded the size is 10MB and the movie is broken ...

here is the code for downloading:

```
 <a href="<?=$video->getFilePath($video->id)?>" download="<?=$video->video_link?>" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">download</a>
```

backend model:

```
 public function getFilePath($id){
    if(isset($id)) {
        $video = ChildVideo::findOne($id);
        if ($video) {
            $path = Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->baseUrl . "/child_video/" . $this->getImageFolderName($id) . "/" . $video->video_link;
        }
    }
}
```

here i upload a video

```
 $modelVideo->setVideoFolder();
            $modelVideo->videoFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'videoFiles');
            if (isset($modelVideo->videoFiles) and count($modelVideo->videoFiles) > 0) {
                foreach ($modelVideo->videoFiles as $key => $file) {
                    $sqllastVideo = "SELECT id FROM child_video WHERE child_id=".$model->user_id." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
                    $lastVideo = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sqllastVideo)->queryOne();
                    $countlastVideo = ChildVideo::find()->where('child_id=:child_id',[':child_id'=>$model->user_id])->orderBy('id DESC')->all();

                    if(count($countlastVideo)<=1 or $lastVideo[0]['id'] = Null) {
                        $orderlastVideo = 1;
                    }else{
                        $orderlastVideo = $lastVideo['id'] + 1;

                    }

                    $file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web') . '/child_video/'.$model->getImageFolderName().'/video_' . $model->user_id . '_' . ($orderlastVideo) . '.' . $file->extension);
                    $pic = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web') . '/child_video/'.$model->getImageFolderName().'/video_' . $model->user_id . '_' . ($orderlastVideo) . '.' . $file->extension;
                    $modelVideos = new ChildVideo;
                    $modelVideos->child_id = $model->user_id;
                    $modelVideos->video_link = 'video_'. $model->user_id . '_' . ($orderlastVideo) . '.' . $file->extension;
                    $modelVideos->active = 3;
                    $modelVideos->save(false);
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'app.Your video is upload successfully!'));
                }
            }
```

Comment: are you doing this on local machine or live ?

Comment: on local machine with linux system

Comment: I can assure you that there will be no backend mechanism that is auto-compressing video files on upload (or any other form of processing). You have shown no code that actually handles the upload process. No mention of the formats involved etc. Nobody will be able to help you with the question in it's current state.